# Не выводится структура вида пары ключ значение

Tags: javascript

```js
function printprops() {
    var a=[10,{"id":10,"pid":15},1,4,["php",5,6],"javascript"];
    for(var key in a){
        console.log(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: вы выводите ключи, и не выводите значения, в чем проблема? кроме того цикл `for..in` не рекомендуется использовать с массивами

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function printprops() {
    var a=[10,{"id":10,"pid":15},1,4,["php",5,6],"javascript"];
    for(var key in a){
        console.log(a[key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

вы выводите ключи, и не выводите значения. кроме того цикл `for..in` не рекомендуется использовать с массивами.

В данном случае можно использовать [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var a = [10, {
    "id": 10,
    "pid": 15
  },
  1, 4, ["php", 5, 6], "javascript"
];

a.forEach(function(el, index) {
  console.log({
    [index]: el
  });
  document.write(JSON.stringify({
    [index]: el
  }) + '<br />');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Подправлено

```js
function printprops() {
 var a = [10, {
   "id": 10,
   "pid": 15
  },
  1, 4, ["php", 5, 6], "javascript"
 ];
 for (var i = 0, length1 = a.length; i < length1; i++) {
  document.write(i + " " + JSON.stringify(a[i]) + "<br>");
  console.log(i + " " + JSON.stringify(a[i]));
 }
}

printprops();
```

Comment: `1 [object Object]`? :-)

Comment: @Grundy если рассудить с этой точки зрения, то и вы выводите в консоль первое значение цифру 10 объектом, а не просто цифру 10. Хотя бы так, михо, http://jsbin.com/kezuqibufo/edit?js,output

Comment: :) не понял про десять объектом :-) я вывожу _только_ объекты, в которых ключ - это индекс элемента, а значение - сам элемент. Я к тому. что вместо `{      "id": 10,      "pid": 15    }` вы выводите `[object Object]`

Comment: @Grundy ну так зачем выводить первое значение объектом, если задача просто вывести ключ/значение? Например, элемент с нулевым индексом или индексом 5.

Comment: например, чтобы показать что это _структура_ :) но замечание было конкретно по выводу `[object Object]` вместо реального строкового представления значения :)

Comment: @Grundy Это я понял, огрызнулся справедливости ради несовершенности вашего скрипта, человек спрашивает вывод пары ключ/значения, в итоге получает вывод в консоль объектов.

Comment: в итоге получает вывод в консоль объектов, которые показываются в виде пары: ключ - значение :)

Comment: Ну и на самом деле вопрос плохой и точно не известно чего именно хочет автор

Comment: @Grundy и возможно не имеет представления работы с объектами, ототожэ..